# What is the probability that exactly $2$ people have exactly $2$ hats?

Tags: probability

**Problem**

> There are $20$ people standing in a line and $8$ of them have hats. If in one turn everyone with a hat gives the hat to the person either in front of them or behind them with equal probability, what is the probability that exactly $2$ people have exactly $2$ hats in $4$ turns?

This question seems hard because there would be multiple situations in which this a set of people with hats could occur. How do I account of this?

**Edited Problem**

> There are $20$ people standing in a line and $8$ of them have hats. If in one turn everyone with a hat gives the hat to the person either in front of them or behind them with equal probability and both events are independent (unless the person is at the end then he/she must pass it to the right or left), what is the probability that exactly $2$ people have exactly $2$ hats in $4$ turns?

Comment: Is this well posed?  Suppose I have two hats.  Must I give both of them to the person in front or behind me or is each one an independent $50-50$ bet?

Comment: Initially, are the hats randomly distributed? Has each person with hat exacly one hat?

Comment: @lulu Yes, I edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: What does "Yes" mean?  I gave two possibilities.  Your edit has not appeared yet.

Comment: Notice the phrase "with equal probability."

Comment: The question concerned the independence.  If both hats must go to the same person it could still be equal probability.  Also, the question should be edited to respond to the comment by @ajotatxe.

Comment: @lulu Not necessarily. You must take into account all possible distributions for the hats.

Comment: Currently, there is a plethora of hats being passed on :)

Comment: What about the persons at the ends ?

Comment: @trueblueanil So it would seem.  I'm not getting the rules here...am I being dense?

Comment: Okay, I edited the problem.

Comment: My best guess as to the rules (but really it's just a guess):  initially $8$ people have exactly one hat  (the rest have no hats) and each possible choice of the $8$ is equally likely.  On any round, each person gives away all their hats, each hat going up or down $1$ in the line with equal probability (the end people just pass all their hats to their only neighbor).

Comment: @lulu You are correct you should assume equal distribution.

Comment: Sorry...I'm not having any ideas better than simulation.  Is there any reason to imagine that there is a pleasing analytic solution?